# Pandoc export to Markdown doesn't include images

Tags: microsoft-word, images, pandoc

I have a Word document that contains a TOC, various headings level 1, 2 & 3, some tables and some images.

When I export to md using `pandoc -f docx -t markdown` the resultant .MD when viewed in Chrome has no images. Instead, I see something like `{width="6.268055555555556in" height="3.2933442694663166in"}` but no actual image.

Do I have to add a tag to the images for Pandoc to export them out?

Comment: Did you try with `--extract-media=media`?

Comment: Tried to add that, and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: How do the images exactly look in the Markdown after that? Is the `media` folder created?

Comment: No different, still just {width} and {height} tags and no sub-dir.

Comment: What about `--extract-media=.`? If still nothing, what kind of images are these?

Comment: Still nothing. They're screenshots from a webforms application pasted into Word from the clipboard. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to get this working by passing in `--extract-media="c:\help\output"` which creates a sub-directory of `\media`.

The MD file then has a path to the image as `![](c:\help\output/media/image1.png)` so I have to then change the path in the MD to `![alt text](media/image1.png)`.

The image then loads in the browser.

**EDIT**: I later found out that by using `-t markdown_mmd` I don't need to edit the path to the file.

Kudos to @Destroy666 for the assist.

Comment: one can also specify  `--extract-media="./"` which then creates relative paths directly.